# WYSIWYG editor in Lwc

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, lightninginput

I have tried using lightning-input-rich-text component to create a WYSIWYG in LWC but given its issues with table ([hitting backspace on table content deletes whole table](https://github.com/salesforce/lwc/issues/3003)) and image (unable to resize image), color picker (impossible to use standard color picker) etc I have started exploring 3rd party JS libraries like quillJs, CkeEditor and TinyMce.
QullJs and CkeEditor throws exceptions when promise is resolved but TinyMce Api works good.

This is the code I am using for TinyMce :

```
import tiny from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/tiny';        
import { loadStyle, loadScript } from 'lightning/platformResourceLoader';

export default class TestPackages extends LightningElement {
    quillInitialised;

    renderedCallback() {
        if (this.quillInitialised) {
            return;
        }
        this.quillInitialised = true;

        Promise.all([
            loadScript(this, tiny)
        ])
            .then(() => {
                this.initQuill();
            })
            .catch(error => {
                debugger;
            });
    }

    initQuill() {
        let qjs = this.template.querySelector('.quil');
        let editor = document.createElement('textarea');
        editor.setAttribute('id', 'quilid');   

        tinymce.init({
            selector: 'textarea#quilid'
        });
qjs.appendChild(editor);
```

and this is html :

```
<template>
    <p>testing packages</p>
    <div lwc:dom="manual" class="quil" id ="quil"></div>
</template>
```

so I can see *qjs.appendChild(editor);* being executed but neither my div tag is being changed nor the editor is inserted into dom.

Not sure what I am missing here. Can anyone please suggest what I am missing or other ways to achieve WYSIWYG editors in Lwc ? Thanks

Comment: Did you include the CSS as well?

Comment: @sfdcfox - No. I have slightly changed the code to remove css (doing some experiments to get basic code working). it is based on https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/tinymce/6/basic-setup/#selector-configuration

Comment: https://codepen.io/rahulbsai/pen/LYdoMRK is the codepen example

Comment: @sfdcfox - sorry for the direct mention here, do you have any insights please or suggestions on any alternate solutions ?