# WYSIWYG editor for LWC?

Tags: apex, visualforce, lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components

I am looking for WYSIWYG editor to read and edit from salesforce.

I have an external system that uses WYSIWYG editor, whereas in Salesforce we are using HTML editor.

Can anyone suggest the best way to read the below code in Salesforce?

Looks like Salesforce already using it somewhere but not sure how I can utilize it?

Check the Trusted Partner : https://quilljs.com/

**Code:**

```
{
    "version": 1,
    "type": "doc",
    "content": [
        {
            "type": "heading",
            "attrs": {
                "level": 1
            },
            "content": [
                {
                    "type": "text",
                    "text": "Hello World"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

**Output:**

> **Hello World**

Note: (Can't afford paid app, need to use inside Manage Package)

Reference But No Answer: [WYSIWYG editor in Lwc](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/383935/wysiwyg-editor-in-lwc)

Comment: What distinction are you making between an HTML editor and a WYSIWYG editor, and what is it that is being edited? It seems you are suggesting to store the markup as JSON instead of HTML? Have you thought about using a simple HTML<->JSON mapping (so the editing is done as HTML but the data is stored as specifically structured JSON)?

Comment: HI @PhilW Thanks for your reply, Yes I do find one Rust code repo 

https://github.com/wouterken/htmltoadf 

before I start learning the code and manually convert this huge lines, is there any simple way to achieve this ?

Comment: Looks like the salesforce content builder is using the WYSIWYG editor, does it make any difference? Can we utilize it in some way?

Comment: @PhilW it is an external system field value, they are using WYSIWYG editor for their rich text fields, I need to show in salesforce and also allow them to edit.